# Choose a class depending on the class' attribute

Tags: java

I want to write a method in java that will select certain words based on an input.
For example, if the choices were a dog, cat, lizard, eagle
and someone types in wings, it'll check to see if the choices have that attribute.

I don't know how complex this is but we've learned for loops, return, if, else and scanners so far.

Comment: Hi Ben! You're not going to learn much if we do the homework for you.  What have you tried so far, or at least what are you thinking of trying in order to accomplish this task? Code with a specific problem/question is best.

Comment: I don't see this problem having a very simple or elegant solution unless you know something about creating different classes and instances of those classes. Have you learned anything about those sorts of things in your class yet?

Comment: Based on your list of things you have learned, I wouldn't think you have covered this subject yet.

Comment: the homework has a table which lists the freezing and boilng points of several substances and I have to write a program that asks the user for a temperature.  based on the input the program should list all the substances within that temperature range. 

perhaps I'm taking the wrong approach.

Comment: well to further explain the assignment, the program should list the subtances based on the input. so for example if user enters -100 it should list water and whatever else on the list freezes at this temperature.
how should i approach this assignment?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably maintain a list of attributes for each object, then check if the user typed attribute is part of the list for all object types you have in hand.

I suggest you look at the [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) JavaDoc, you will need to use it to maintain the list of attributes. If you don't feel at ease with using an `ArrayList` object to hold onto your attributes, you may want to use a `String` array instead, which will work fine too. You will also need to defined a class hierarchy and define a method that will be available in all subclasses (here's a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) on inheritance).

#### Edit

I posted this first answer before reading the comments.

If your only assignment is to provide a list of components that freeze at the user specified temperature, then a list of attributes isn't necessary. You can define a super class (lets say `Element`) that will define an abstract method `public int getFreezingTemperature ()`. Then, in all subclasses, you will have to implement this method. As an example, if you create a class `Water`:

```
public class Water extends Element {
    @Override
    public int getFreezingTemperature () {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And repeat the same for every element you have to create. Once you are done, whenever a user inputs a temperature, you can query your elements via the method `getFreezingTemperature ()`, and whenever the returned temperature is above the user specified temperature, add it to a list of elements that freeze at the specified temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: after reading your comments, it looks like you're going to want to do something like this.

```
//create your scanner, using whatever resource you are told to use
int temp=scanner.readInt()

//read in the given temperatures
if(substance1freezingpoint > temp){
    System.out.println("substances 1 will freeze at " + temp);
}
if(substance2freezingpoint > temp){
    System.out.println("substance 2 will freeze at " + temp);
}
....
```

A couple of things to note about that implementation.

1. It assumes that more than one substance can freeze at temp.  If that isn't the case, you're going to want to use else ifs.  As a question to test your learning: why is that?
2. It doesn't store which substances will freeze at a certain temperature, it just prints them out to the screen.  How would you modify this to store the substances which meet the criteria
3. It doesn't deal with boiling points, but it's a pretty easy modification to make it do that.

So, does that code at least get you off on the right foot, or does it not satisfy what the problem is asking?

Comment: i have not learned arrays. considering everyone mentioned arrays I think the professor wanted us to write a bunch of if/else statements to test our knowledge in it for this assignment.

Comment: Ah, reading fail.  Do you know the set of substances you will be given?

Comment: Yes, I have a list of 4 substances and they each have a freezing point and boiling point.

Comment: Edited the post, check it to tell me if there's anything else you need.

Comment: sorry for the late response. I figured out a way to do it with just if statements and it turned out to look very similar to what you posted 
`code` 
public static String calculate(int a)
         {
         if(a <= 32)
         
            {
            System.out.println("Water freezes.");
            }
         if(a <= -38)
            {
            System.out.println("Mercury freezes.");
            }

and etc for all the numbers that were given.

Answer (score 0):

I'm attempting to answer the substance-temperature question you mentioned in your comment. You could make an arrays as such:

```
String[] substances = new String[number of substances given];
```

Then place the substances into the array in the same order that they are given in the assignment. You can then check the user's input and determine at which index the name of the substance corresponding with their input is. For example:

```
//code to initialize array of substances goes here, call it "substArray"
//code to make scanner goes here, call it "scan"
int temp = scan.nextInt();
if(temp == -100)
{
System.out.println(substArray[index of substance corresponding with -100]);
}
else if...
...
```

This seems to be a very messy and a not very elegant program to write without use of separate classes, but hopefully this is within the range of your current knowledge and understanding.
 I hope this helps,
       Tyler